# Processing Json stored as a HashMap with multiple elements stored in values

Tags: java, json, hashmap, jackson

I have a json document with multiple objects. I have managed to print this out as a map but I want to be able to access elements within the values.

I can print the Map, but want to be able to print specific elements within the keys

```
for (Map.Entry<String,Object> entry : myMap.entrySet()) {
        System.out.println("Key: "+entry.getKey() + " Value: "+entry.getValue());
    }
```

This outputs the following:

```
Key: header1 Value: {id=123456, contents=[cat,dog,hamster]}
Key: header2 Value: {id=234567, contents=[spoon,knife,fork]}
```

I would like to be able to loop through and on each iteration assign id to a string and contents to a list

Comment: What have you tried so far. Sounds like homework and is too broad.

Comment: Sadly I am a bit old for homework! My issue is I'm not really sure if what I'm asking is possible with the data structure without using a split or something equally bodged! I am trying to access with something like `myMap.get("contents")` but this doesn't work and I'm not really sure what sort of thing I should be looking up with regards to the syntax

Comment: @NicholasK looks like someone has done his homework. :)

Answer (score 1):

The easiest solution is to make a Class, which represents the JSON. For you, it will be like this:

```
public class Contents {
    private int id;
    private List<String> contents;

    //No arguments constructor, getters and setters for every field
    //You can make with @JsonCreator, too. Read Jackson documentation
};
```

Then you just read it as object using Jackson's ObjectMapper:

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
Contents result = mapper.readValue(entry.getValue(), Contents.class);
```

After, this you can do whatever you like with the object. Later, you can even write it to File/Stream etc.

Answer (score 0):

I had a couple of issues with code I had assume to be working but have solved this now with a little help from a colleague.

```
value.getContents();
```

Was the thing I was looking for!